# Max-height on Bootstrap accordion with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to set a max-height on a Bootstrap accordion in an AngularJS app, such that the whole accordion can be made to fit on screen and only the expanded pane scroll it's content if needed?

So far I've only been able to have the whole accordion scroll, rather than the content.

**Edit to add:**

A bare-bones plunk of what I've been working with:   http://plnkr.co/edit/97fqbx1Wg84hcTpW24Yi?p=preview

To get the content of each panel to scroll properly I've tried variants of:

```
.content {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but since the parent elements are all full-height regardless of any CSS I've tried that doesn't do any good.

I've tried setting heights and max-heights on every combination of the relevant elements but nothing seems to get close, especially taking into account the fact that the accordion will hold an unknown number of items.

Comment: Please share your code, what you've tried, and where you're stuck. But it seems you are looking to modify the bootstrap CSS code to determine what is scrollable and what isn't. Since you tagged this as an angular question, here's a blank template of plunker to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=preview

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @Andy?

Comment: @blomster - I had to switch to using a jQuery UI accordion in the end.  Mixing jQuery UI with Angular was less than ideal but at least it had the behaviour I needed.